# Access-Control-Allow-Origin for ajax call and HttpURLConnection

Tags: java, jquery, ajax, httpurlconnection

I was trying to access a web-url(which I dont have access over) which will return a JSON formatted string.

I tried with AJAX call and it shows ''**No Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource**' .

Then I found a workaround to get JSON DATA using '**HttpURLConnection**'

Can someone please tell me how both works,because requests are made from localhost only.

Below is my code in both the ways:

**AJAX:**

```
var request = $.ajax({
    url: "url",
    type: "Get",
    crossDomain: true,
    data: "ingredients=" + ingredientList,
    dataType: 'json'
});
```

**HttpURLConnection:**

```
URL obj = new URL(url);
        HttpURLConnection con = (HttpURLConnection) obj.openConnection();
        con.setRequestMethod("GET");
        int responseCode = con.getResponseCode();
```

Answer (score 0):

just write `data: ingredientList,` instead the object should be automatically format

Answer (score 0):

It's difficult to check solution without real URL, but it's well known problem. I can advise you to try add `dataType: 'jsonp'` instead of `dataType: 'json'`.